# Variable suddenly changing inside fork() child process C - very weird behaviour

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork

I'm hoping someone here could help me cause I'm witnessing some weird behavior from my C code.

I have a Linux shell-like program in C. The code is 250 lines long, so I can't be posting it here.

In short, I have this function for non-built in commands:

```
int not_builtin(char** args, int background, char* line) {
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("fork failed\n");
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
            printf("exec failed\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (!background) {
            if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {
                printf("An error occurred\n");
            }
        }
        add_job(line, pid, background);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When I run my shell on my PC (Macbook), everything works as expected. BUT, when I run this on my university server (Linux), I get a bug. I cannot properly debug this since on my computer everything works fine. The bug is it outputs: `"exec failed"` for any command (line 9).

By printing through the code, I was able to detect the following behavior:
The `char** args` are good throughout the code, I printed them until just before the "`if (pid == 0)"`.

Once you enter the if statement mentioned above, printing the args returns some garbage.

Specifically, for an input:  `$ ls -l`
I got printed `ls -l` before the if, and `?\??` after the if.
Like this for any other command string.

What could be the reason?

The whole day the program worked fine. It started to happen once I changed my "parse-line" function, to copy the line before editing. It now looks like this:

```
char** parse_line(char *line, int *background) {
    char line_copy[BUFF_SIZE];
    strcpy(line_copy, line);
    char **tokens = malloc(BUFF_SIZE*sizeof(char*));
    if (!tokens) {
        printf("An error occurred\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int position = 0;
    char *token;
    token = strtok(line_copy, DELIM);
    while (token) {
        tokens[position] = token;
        position++;
        token = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }

    // change the background option
    if (position > 0 && strcmp(tokens[position-1], "&")==0) {
        *background = 1;
        tokens[position-1]=NULL;
        line[strlen(line)-2] = '\0';
    } else {
        *background = 0;
        tokens[position] = NULL;
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Before the change I would perform the `strtok` directly on `line`, but now I figured I need that value intact. But how is this connect in any way?

Any help would be MUCH appreciated

Comment: `token = strtok(line_copy, DELIM); tokens[position] = token;` Undefined behaviour because `line_copy` is a local variable. Invalid to use references to a local variable once the function exits.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. Do you have an idea on how to solve this? I want to keep the line string intact. Maybe I can copy it _before_ calling the function, and then call with the copied value?

Comment: Yes or make a copy into dynamic memory inside the function.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the first two lines of the `parse_line()` to:
`char *line_copy = malloc(BUFF_SIZE*sizeof(char*));
strcpy(line_copy, line);`
It now works fine! Do I have to free the memory of the `line_copy`? If I do, I get the same bug. I need the args later on so I suppose I can't. On the other hand, shouldn't I?
Keep in mind I free the `args` and `line` altogether at the end of the program.

Comment: It's up to you to define the API. If the function API is such that dynamic memory is allocated inside the function then either a "free" API is also provided or it is defined that the caller needs to do the free when the data is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks. I can't free it from the function, since I need the args later on (args==tokens). How can I do this then?